# SharedPreference in fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences

```
Public void saveData() {
   SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRI. VATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putString(TEXT,edit name.getText().toString());
   editor.apply();
}
```

I have used `SharedPreferences` in `fragment`. 
And I want to use `SharedPreferences` data from `fragment` in `mainActivity`. 
How can I do this? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `singleton class` for `SharedPreference` and then you can access it from any `activity` or `fragment` you want.

**Example**

```
public class SessionManager {
  private static SessionManager jInstance;
  private final SharedPreferences prefs;
  private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  private SessionManager(Context context) {
      prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your_Preference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      editor = prefs.edit();
  }

  public static synchronized SessionManager getInstance(Context context) {
      if (jInstance != null) {
          return jInstance;
      } else {
          jInstance = new SessionManager(context);
          return jInstance;
      }
  }

  public void setUserEmail(String userEmail){
      editor.putString("user_email",userEmail);
      editor.apply();
  }
  public String getUserEmail(){
      return prefs.getString("user_email","");
  }
}
```

Now you can user SessionManager from any `activity` or `fragment` like below.

```
SessionManager.getInstance(context).setUserEmail("abc@gmail.com");
String email = SessionManager.getInstance(context).getUserEmail();
```